# Improve Script Performance when Running Remotely

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have script which is used by my office.  The install priveledges are restricted and installing Python on every machine would have been a hassle, so I installed Anaconda to the server.  It works great if you have an Ethernet cable, its slow if you're on WiFi, and if you VPN in to the server, it flat out doesn't work (I get the script's splash screen, then nothing).

That last bit is a problem!

Are there any tricks I can do in Python that will allow the script to run when the connection to the Python executable and script are awful?

Comment: Same problem here, with both python code and site-packages installed remotely (~20s startup time vs <1s locally). Up-voting question, it *is* relevant.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you should investigate [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) which allows you to run an executable without requiring a Python installation.  On OSX, you should investigate [py2app](http://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) which is very similar.
I am not aware of an equivalent for Linux.

I think these will allow you to create a single self-contained executable which should greatly reduce the network overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I've looked into ```py2exe``` and it won't work for me for a couple reasons.  The biggest is that I can't create a single executable because of some dependency (I forget which).

Comment: I suspect poor performance will most likely be caused by the way Python inspects the PYTHONPATH when loading modules (including those from site-packages such as `os`).  Each import will be triggering multiple stats on the filer, resulting in many round trips with the client.  Check that the PYTHONPATH is as short as possible, and collapse paths where possible.  Also consider creating a zip (http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) for importing (but this will depend on your dependencies).

Comment: Unfortunately its a giant script (~8000 lines) with a lot of dependencies (~40 imports) which I don't think I can eliminate without a massive overhaul (and even then I could maybe get rid of 6?)

Comment: But you can collect your dependencies so they appear as one entry in the PYTHONPATH - this is assuming they are not already install in site-packages.  The number of entries in PYTHONPATH will have a greater impact on performance than the number of imports/dependencies in my experience.